# Is there an appropriate way to show correlation or causation from a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I'm curious if there's any way that Microsoft Access or SQL Server can provide a function to show correlation or causation from a SQL Select statement and its results.

This is basically the use case scenario:

Let's say you have two tables, table `studentCourseSurveys` and table `onlineCourseReviews`. At the forefront these two tables are mostly unrelated but could be joined based on the course name, for example "ENG 101".

`studentCourseSurveys` is a table that is intended to hold data that students submit during
their in person course survey at the end of a semester. For example, in the last day of class students receive that form to fill out to rate the instructor based on things such as "exams were related to the actual lecture content", "instructor was on time and prepared", and then at the end they have their short answer opportunities to give additional comments.

`onlineCourseReviews` is a table that is used by an internal department that conducts content reviews on the online component of courses. For example, this department has individual instructional designers who are assigned different courses in Blackboard to review. They review content, delivery, course structure, and so on and so forth. The course is then given its comments, score, etc.

As already mentioned the tables would be most unrelated. But let's say someone wanted to show a correlation that the results of the online course reviews could somehow indicate that the quality of the overall course was better because of these online reviews, and that this was shown in the responses from the students based on their survey results.(basically, a course that got an online course review score of 10 has course surveys where a great majority of the students rated it as excellent, content was relevant, teacher was prepared, etc, to indicate that an improvement in the online course translated to improvements in the in-person class and overall class quality).

This almost seems like a unique job for a statistician but I'd like to know if it's possible to show this data based on a query in Access or SQL Server. I know that you could just easily join the two tables with a foreign key and then get the results of a survey and online course review in a single statement but that doesn't really say anything. I would think that to show ANY kind of relationship that you need to illustrate a trend over any given period of time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest creating a query with three values - course name (e.g., ENG101), the student rating, and the online course rating.  In SQL Server you can save the results as a .csv file.  Do this, then open it in Excel and use the [RSQ function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rsq-function-HP010342863.aspx) , or R-Squared, to find the [correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient) between columns two and three.  The closer R-squared is to 1, the closer the two match. 1 mean a perfect correlation.  0 means no relation at all and -1 means related but but in a polar opposite manner.

Comment: Will there be any decimal values in between -1 and 1 to symbolize how how much closer to a perfect match is and vice versa?(how far something is from a match)?

Comment: Yes.  Anything above .90 (IMHO) is a good sign that there is very good correlation.  Anything can be compared in this manner.  Let's say course attendance and high student ratings for example (or poor for both).

Comment: Does it make sense or is it rational(can't think of the right word to use)to take two values and standardize them for comparison? The course survey has no total score; the scores recorded are just the averages from all student responses for a given question. Whereas the course review has a maximum total score of 80. So can you take all of those averages from the course survey, and get THAT average(for a single value), and, take the total score from a course review, multiply it by a factor of .20, and then use those two values in the RSQ function?

Comment: You shouldn't need to adjust for correlation, which is a bit of an exception in statistics.  Might be good to post some sample data too. It is, BTW, a very interesting question.  It would be good to look at courses without online classes against those that do.  But it all depends on the instructors unless you have a large amount of data.